# Extract data from PHP curl response

Tags: php, json, curl

> My code is

```
$url = "URL";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$result = curl_exec($curl); 
var_dump($result);
$json = json_decode($result);
print_r($json);

curl_close($curl);
```

> The response from **var_dump($result)** is -

```
string(1866) "{"status":true,"result":[{"time":"2016-11-15T19:20:27.000Z"},{"time":"2016-11-15T19:18:15.000Z"},{"time":"2016-11-15T19:15:03.000Z"},
```

> The response I get from **print_r($json)** is -

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 1
    [result] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [time] => 2016-11-15T19:20:27.000Z
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [time] => 2016-11-15T19:18:15.000Z
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [time] => 2016-11-15T19:15:03.000Z
            )
```

I need the value of time into some variable.

> Something I have done in Javscript is -

```
var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttpSerie.responseText);
response.forEach(function(items)
{
    currentTime = items.time;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how do I get the value of time from the response in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $json['result'][0]['time'];`

> EDIT after major changes to the original question:

You need to use the second parameter of `json_decode()` to convert objects to associative arrays. Then you can use `foreach()` to cycle through the array and print times:

```
$json = json_decode($result, TRUE);
foreach ($json['result'] as $index => $v) {
  echo $v['time'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: I get this error - `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/html/fileName.php on line 45`

Comment: @SMG: Are you sure you have the line `$json = json_decode($result, true);` just before the `echo`?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: `string(1866) "{"status":true,"result":[{"time":"2016-11-15T19:20:27.000Z"`  - This is the output

Comment: Is it because I have more than one instances of time in my response? I edited my code with the exact outputs.

Comment: No, it is because you omitted `TRUE` from `json_decode()` call. But if you expect to have multiple times in the result, it would be better to use `foreach`: `foreach ($json['result'] as $index => $v) echo $v['time'];`